# Finetuning GPT-2 in huggingface's pytorch-transformers library

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am looking to finetune the huggingface's GPT-2 PyTorch model.
https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-transformers/tree/master

I read the *'Examples'* section in their documentation where they have shown an example of training the old GPT model on RocStories dataset.
https://huggingface.co/pytorch-transformers/examples.html#fine-tuning

I would like to know how to perform this kind of training for GPT-2. Also, my dataset doesn't have an *'Evaluation Set'*. I simply want to finetune GPT-2 on my dataset and then use it to generate new text which is 'similar' to the dataset it was finetuned on.

I am pretty sure I am missing something somewhere in the documentation. 
I would be glad if anyone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Hi Pranjal, we are working on updating the fine-tuning example in the repo.

Comment: Thanks for the response @julien_c, looking forward to the update.

Comment: Implementing [ULMFiT](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.06146) for task specific finetuning is fairly easy using fastai library.